# Toggle state with useState in React wont work as an object

Tags: reactjs, boolean, toggle, react-hooks

Toggling the state from true to false like this works fine in react using hooks every time toggleTest function is executed:

```
const [testToggler, setTest] = useState(false);

const toggleTest = () => {
    setTest(!testToggler);
    console.log(testToggler);
}
```

But when Im sending it as an object it wont toggle. Howcome?

```
const [testToggler, setTest] = useState({ label: 'test', val: false });

const toggleTest = () => {
    setTest({label: 'test', val: !testToggler} );
    console.log(testToggler);
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`testToggler` is an object, so `!testToggler` is always false.

You probably want the `.val` property.